# Актуальность css стиля

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Нам нужно получить стили элемента, которые прописаны ему, то есть конкретно в файле стилей. Но загвоздка в том, что стили могут переопределяться. Например если мы сделаем так:

```
var style = $("#menu").css([
    "width", "height", "color", "margin", "background-color"
]);
console.log(style);
```

Так мы узнаем значения конкретных стилей. Но минус в том, что если в самом файле не прописан стиль width, то нам jquery все равно выведет ширину элемента.
Надеялся, что библиотека phpQuery имеет метод css, который получит стили, но увы.

Вопрос: каким способом ещё можно получить только актуальные стили элемента? С помощью javascript, query или php - любой способ актуален.

P.S.: Если мы посмотрим в консоль хрома или файребаг, то заметим, что в колонке со стилями, браузер определяет какой стиль переопределяет предыдущий, как раз то что и требуется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: jQuery тут не поможет, а php - тем более.

Comment: какой собственно в этом всем действе смысл?

Comment: Если стили с другого домена, кроссдоменность не позволит, по крайней мере, в хроме.

Comment: @Qwertiy видимо не дождусь тут ответа, но в любом случае я это сделаю тогда сам.

Comment: @teran не могу сказать, коммерческая тайна)

Comment: `var el = $0;

var ss = document.styleSheets;
for (var q=0; q<ss.length; ++q) {
  var rs = document.styleSheets[q].rules;
  if (rs) {
    for (var w=0; w<rs.length; ++w) {
      if (el.matches(rs.selectorText)) {
        console.log(rs);
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Я же не писал что процесс происходит на стороннем домене.

Comment: @Qwertiy Uncaught TypeError: el.matches is not a function

Comment: @Владимир, ну, я в хроме проверял. Вот названия метода под разные браузеры: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

Comment: @Qwertiy я всегда в хроме работаю